# Css style of local file and github site unsynced

Tags: html, css, github

[Menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP9e3.png)

My menu bar elements got overlapped like in the screenshot on my github site but it displays well in local file view.

Here is my html block:

```
    <div class="heading">
      <span class="logo">

          <a href="#top"><img src="./images/logo2.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
          <p><a href="#top">Vu Nguyen</a></p>

      </span>
      <span id="menu">
        <a href="#top">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Here is my css style

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: initial;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.heading {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.heading span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.logo img {
  width: 80px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.logo p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: large;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

[Menu bar actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65D9C.png)

This is what it looks like in my local file view and also what I want it to look like.

The css is nowhere near clean, I hope if I can get any advise too but my main problem is that what displays in my local view vs what shows on github are 2 different things. And it's pretty slow to get github to update so every trial and fail has took me quite a lot of time to fix them.

I also went with `<header class="#header"></header>` to wrap the menu too but the problem appear to be worse when `margin` or `left` attributes didn't do anything to affect it on github but my local view got huge impact.

Is it my code problem or it's github deployment a mess?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed;` from `.heading`.

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document.

An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) for **position: fixed**-

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout.

Comment: I was trying to make the menu flow with the page when scrolling like a navigator. I think the margin does help a little bit if I make the value big enough. When I set ``margin-left:  30%`` for the .menu, it space out from the left side and not overlapping with the logo. But it's stills not synced with the local file view. I meant, the code display fine on local view, I just don't understand why is it different on github site.

Comment: @VuNguyen You should try `position: sticky;`.